# Android emulator cannot find audio files for music player app

Tags: java, android, audio

I am working on a simple music player app, and querying the content resolver as follows:

```
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "!= 0";
        String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC";
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, selection, null, sortOrder);

        audioList = new ArrayList<>();
        Log.d("CURSOR IS NULL", (cursor != null) ? "FALSE": "TRUE");
        Log.d("CURSOR COUNT", String.valueOf(cursor.getCount()));
        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                String data = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
                String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE));
                String album = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));
                String artist = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));

                // Save to audioList
                audioList.add(new Audio(data, title, album, artist));
                Log.d("DEBUG TITLE", title);
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
```

I've seen many similar issues on this website but none of the solutions have worked for me. It always reports a value of 0 for getCount(). My Android manifest has the following permissions (I know write is not needed in this case):

```
    <!-- allow storage access -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I have copied the music files as follows:

1. into /mnt/sdcard/Music via Device File Explorer (Right click -> Upload)
2. dragging and dropping into emulator and copying them from the internal storage Download folder into the sdcard Music folder using the Files app

None of them seem to work. I have read that mediastore needs to reindex these, and have tried the following solutions:

1. Cold-boot the virtual device from Android Virtual Device Manager
2. Running the following in adb shell

```
for ANDROID_MEDIA in $(find /mnt/sdcard/Music/*.mp3); 
do am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE -d "${ANDROID_MEDIA}"; done
```

which reports

```
Broadcasting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE dat=/mnt/sdcard/Music/bensound-betterdays.mp3 flg=0x400000 }
Broadcast completed: result=0
Broadcasting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE dat=/mnt/sdcard/Music/bensound-dubstep.mp3 flg=0x400000 }
Broadcast completed: result=0
Broadcasting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE dat=/mnt/sdcard/Music/bensound-epic.mp3 flg=0x400000 }
Broadcast completed: result=0
Broadcasting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE dat=/mnt/sdcard/Music/bensound-funnysong.mp3 flg=0x400000 }
Broadcast completed: result=0
Broadcasting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE dat=/mnt/sdcard/Music/bensound-sunny.mp3 flg=0x400000 }
Broadcast completed: result=0
```

I can freely play those music files from the Files app, or Youtube music, but my app simply does not find them no matter what. Can someone please tell me if I am missing anything? I am new to Android development

Many thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to the AndroidManifest.xml file in **application** tag.

```
<application
.....
  android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
....
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately this did not change anything, cold booted again too

Answer (score 0):

I had a kind of similar problem when files were not read from memory (did not appear on app).

In my case .
**(SOLUTION) --> I set up sdcard as my additional storage. It was a notification on virtual device phone and then I was guided through the procedure.**
I assume it would be accessible also from virtual device phone -->settings --> storage.

! alse be sure to have your desired file(example: photo,music ) in your virual memory (example: from device explorer /sdcard or /musics ). or upload it from your computer to sdcard(from device explorer!)

! Furthermore be aware of your appropriate permissions and api level (under and above android 10).

I hope it may help someone :)